# Oracle Internet Directory 12.2.1.3.0 oid_setup command error

Tags: oracle, weblogic, oracle12c, weblogic12c, oid

I seriously need your help guys with this error. I have spent days without a headway. kindly help
THIS IS THE OUTPUT

Initializing WebLogic Scripting Tool (WLST) ...

Welcome to WebLogic Server Administration Scripting Shell

Type help() for help on available commands

wls:/offline> connect('weblogic','Oracle_123','t3://mypc:7001')
Connecting to t3://mypc:7001 with userid weblogic ...
Successfully connected to Admin Server "AdminServer" that belongs to domain "mydomain15".

Warning: An insecure protocol was used to connect to the server.
To ensure on-the-wire security, the SSL port or Admin port should be used instead.

wls:/mydomain15/serverConfig/> oid_setup(orcladminPassword='Oracle_123',odsPassword='Oracle_123',realmDN='dc=us,dc=oracle,dc=com')
Location changed to edit custom tree. This is a writable tree with No root.
For more help, use help('editCustom')

Starting an edit session ...
Started edit session, be sure to save and activate your changes once you are done.
Traceback (innermost last):
File "", line 1, in ?
File "/D:/Installations/Middleware/Oracle_Home/oid/plugins/wlst/oid-wlst-dependencies.jar!/wlstScriptDir/OidCustomCommands.py", line 14, in oid_setup
File "D:\Installations\Middleware\Oracle_Home\oid\plugins\wlst\oid-wlst-dependencies.jar\wlstScriptDir/oid_handler.py", line 274, in oid_doSetup
File "D:\Installations\Middleware\Oracle_Home\wlserver\modules\com.oracle.weblogic.management.scripting.jar\weblogic/management/scripting/utils/modules/wlstModule.py", line 38, in invoke
File "C:\Users\PC~1\AppData\Local\Temp\wlst_module16228764592223979273.py", line 753, in wlstInvoke
File "C:\Users\PC~1\AppData\Local\Temp\wlst_module35208756416998744505.py", line 240, in raiseWLSTException
WLSTException: Error occurred while performing invoke : Creation of wallets failed for domain "D:\Installations\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\mydomain15"
Use dumpStack() to view the full stacktrace :
wls:/mydomain15/editCustom/oracle.oid.mbeans/oracle.oid.mbeans:type=OIDSystemComponent,name=OIDComponentManager> dumpStack()
This Exception occurred at Mon Aug 24 23:47:45 GMT 2020.
javax.management.MBeanException: Creation of wallets failed for domain "D:\Installations\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\mydomain15"
at weblogic.utils.StackTraceDisabled.unknownMethod()
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Creation of wallets failed for domain "D:\Installations\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\mydomain15"
... 1 more

javax.management.MBeanException: Creation of wallets failed for domain "D:\Installations\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\mydomain15"
wls:/mydomain1/editCustom/oracle.oid.mbeans/oracle.oid.mbeans:type=OIDSystemComponent,name=OIDComponentManager>

KINDLY HELP ME OUT

Comment: Please Use the `{}` tool from the Edit menu on mouse-selected text to format as `code/data/requiredOutput/ExactErrMsgs`. Good luck.

Comment: You also need to read about [mcve] . Readers will need the minimal amount of code that produces this issue, so please edit your Q to include that. You might want to also include information about OS and other relevant tool versions. (No experience with this problem, I won't be able to help further). Good luck!